# _Mtx_t variable failed ,how i declare it in order to don't reference to null?

Tags: c++

the variable _Mtx_t failed and references null. How i declare it in
    order to all his function doesn't fail?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thread>
#include <conio.h>
#include <mutex>

#include <signal.h>
#include <condition_variable>
#define NUM_READERS 6
#define NUM_READS 5
#define NUM_WRITERS 6
#define NUM_WRITES 5



using namespace std;
_Cnd_t read_phase, write_phase;
int resource_counter = 0;

_Mtx_t counter_mutex = (_Mtx_t)("0x01", "0x02", "0x04", "0x100");
int WaitReaders = 0,Read = 0;
void writer() {

    int i = 0, numReaders = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_WRITES; i++) {

        _Mtx_trylock(counter_mutex); {
                while (Read != 0) {

                    _Cnd_wait(write_phase, counter_mutex);
                }
                Read = -1;
                numReaders = Read;

            }

            _Mtx_unlock(counter_mutex);

        printf( " writing %u* [readers: %2d]\n", ++resource_counter, numReaders);

        _Mtx_lock(counter_mutex); {
            Read = 0;
            if (WaitReaders > 0)
                _Cnd_broadcast(read_phase);

            else
                _Cnd_signal(write_phase);
        }
        _Mtx_unlock(counter_mutex);
        counter_mutex;

    }
}
void Readers() {

    int i = 0, numReaders = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_READS; i++) {
        _Mtx_lock(counter_mutex);
            {
                while (resource_counter == 1)
                {
                    _Cnd_wait(read_phase, counter_mutex);

                }
                WaitReaders--;
                numReaders = ++Read;
            }
            _Mtx_unlock(counter_mutex);
        }

        printf( " reading %u  [readers: %2d]\n",  resource_counter, numReaders);

        _Mtx_lock(counter_mutex); {
            Read--;
            if (Read == 0)
                _Cnd_signal(read_phase);
        }
        _Mtx_unlock(counter_mutex);
    }

int main()
{

    int i;

    int readerNum[NUM_READERS];
    int writerNum[NUM_WRITERS];

    thread readerThreadIDs[NUM_READERS];
    thread writerThreadIDs[NUM_WRITERS];


    for (i = 0; i < NUM_READERS; i++) {
        readerNum[i] = i;
        readerThreadIDs[i] = thread(Readers);
        writerNum[i] = i;
        writerThreadIDs[i] = thread(writer);

    }


    for (i = 0; i < NUM_READERS; i++) {
        readerThreadIDs[i].join();
        writerThreadIDs[i].join();

    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
Exception thrown at 0x79969664 (msvcp140d.dll) in Priority Readers and Writers.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000030.
Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
_Mtx_internal_imp_t::_get_cs(...)->**** was 0x30. occurred
```

Answer (score 0):

`_Cnd_t` ? `_Mtx_t` ? These are types which are internal to your C++ implementation, and they are not intended to be used by you.

You should use `std::mutex` and `std::condition_variable`. Look them up in your C++ book.